# Using "date+'%M', whats the data type, can can I use it as a conditional?

Tags: performance, shell, sh

I'm trying to run a script where on the hour, the script would update something in my directory. So to do this, I define the a function called "min_stamp" by doing:

```
min_stamp(){
    date +%M"
}
```

I would then call on the function continuously in a while loop with this structure:

```
while:
do
    min=min_stamp
    if [$min == 00] then
        "Update directory"
    fi
done
```

The logic is that on the hour, when the minute is 00, the script would do the specified action. So my question is what data type is returned from the function min_stamp, and am I using the variable correctly as a condition to trigger an event.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually calling the function; you're just assigning the string `min_stamp` to the variable `m`. You need to use command substitution:

```
while :
do
  min=$(min_stamp)
  if [ "$min" = 00 ]; then
      ...
  fi
done
```

However, instead of repeated running `min_stamp` to see if you are the top of the hour yet, consider using `cron` to schedule your job.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some task every hour, you should consider to use cron job.

Your shell script codes have syntax problem, such as, the space between `[...]` and the function call etc. More important is, if you used `+%M (minute) == 00` to do the check and start the "update". It means, on every hour, within the first minute, you will keep updating your resources for the whole 60 seconds. because, with your function, e.g. 03:00:00 - 03:00:59 returns the same result: `00`.

It could be billions of times' update. again, use crontab.